# Pathological Examples in Smash Products?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, hausdorff-distance, continuum-theory

I don't normally encounter smash products in the stuff I do, but rn I'm looking at some point-set properties of what are apparently smash products.  My impression is that smash products usually arise in categorical constructions or when you're dealing with some generalized manifolds and want to get a nicer, related space (sorta like how suspensions are used) to study properties of.

Have smash products been studied very much when the spaces aren't as nice?  A continuum is a compact, connected metric space.  Two questions:

1. If $X$ and $Y$ are continua, is $X \wedge Y$ aposyndetic?  Kelley?
2. If $X$ and $Y$ are continua, what is the hyperspace of $X \wedge Y$?

The "hyperspace" is the collection of closed subsets under the Hausdorff metric.  Usually the hyperspace is very large, so a better question is probably this:

2') If $X$ and $Y$ are continua, what is $C(X \wedge Y)$?

Here $C(X \wedge Y)$ is the subset of the hyperspace consisting of the closed, *connected* subsets.

I'm wondering if we can decompose the space nicely assuming the smash is taken at cut points of $X, Y$ respectively, or if there are other constructions that allow extra-nice decomps.  Any ideas or alternatives to get nice, comprehensible spaces?

I'm also curious to know about any strange and unintuitive (or instructive) examples of general, topological smash products when the spaces aren't super-nice.

Comment: A lot of hyperspaces of continua are homeomorpic to $Q$, the Hilbert cube. (i.e. $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ in the product topology). This is true for hyperspaces of Peano continua (metric compact, connected locally connected spaces).

Comment: What do you mean by the smash product? As I encounter it, it is defined for two pointed spaces $X,Y$ and given by $X\wedge Y=(X\times Y)/(X\vee Y)$ (this notation being somewhat standard). I ask because (for me) the notation $X\ast Y$ denotes the join of two unbased spaces $X,Y$.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of the smash product; it can vary depending on base point chosen.  Oops on the notation, I was on my phone and thought ⨳ looked like $*$ haha.

Comment: Ok, I updated the notation, but it seems that ⨳ isn't available for use on this site.  Weird.  Maybe I'm misremembering something but I thought in MacLane's category theory book there was another symbol for smash product, something with a square.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are Hausdorff, then so is $X\wedge Y$. In particular if $X,Y$ are compacta (continua), then so is $X\wedge Y$. However the local connectivity properties of $X\wedge Y$ can be very bad depending on the basepoints of $X,Y$. For example $S^1\wedge\mathbb{N}_\infty$ is the Hawaiian earing ($\mathbb{N}_\infty$ being the harmonic sequence). Here's a trick: if $X,Y$ are compact Hausdorff, then $(X,x_0)\wedge(Y,y_0)$ is the one-point compactification of $(X\setminus x_0)\times(Y\setminus y_0)$.

Comment: (Relevant) question for you, then: if $X$ is a locally compact, separable (connected) metric space with one-point compactification $X_\infty$, then what local properties can you expect from the compactum (continuum) $X_\infty$ at the point $\infty$? (this is a genuine question I don't know the answer to)

Comment: I will think about these facts for a while.  But for example every product of continua is aposyndetic, surprisingly.  A lot of those extreme pathologies don't show up in products, is why I wondered if the smash product would also preserve anything.  I guess with your compactification argument, if $x, y$ are cut points then the smash is gonna be some sort of wedge?  At least if they cut the spaces into finitely many pieces.